# Bless doesn't fix white boot screen boot delay for single-boot Xubuntu 14.04 on Macbook 4,1

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, xubuntu, macbook

I still have a 30-second delay on the white boot-up screen before Xubuntu loads after trying various combinations of bless --device as recommended here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Avoid_long_EFI_wait_before_GRUB

I wonder if anyone has experienced this before, or can point me to some good steps for troubleshooting this issue? I have cycled my macbook dozens of times, it would be great to be able to boot quicker.

I am single-booting Xubuntu 14.04 (no Mac OSX partitions or any other OS, just a GRUB partition at sda1, a main partition at sda2, and a swap at the end of the drive).

Suggestions very appreciated.

Comment: Are you using refind to boot?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already tried variations on the "bless" command, but I can at least confirm that it *is* possible to fix this on a setup just like yours.

I too have a MacBook 4,1 and I just installed Xubuntu 14.04.1 (32-bit) on it a couple of days ago in a single-boot configuration.  Right after install, I was having the 30-second white-gray screen delay problem.  Here's what fixed it for me:

1. Clear PRAM by holding Command-Option-P-R right after the Mac boot chime, and wait until the second boot chime to let go.
2. Boot into a Mac OS X 10.6 installation disc.
3. Run a Terminal, and type the following:

   `bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy --verbose`
4. Shutdown from the installer.
5. Turn on the MacBook and hold down the trackpad button after the chime to eject the installation disc.
6. The laptop should continue booting Xubuntu after the disc ejects.

Following that procedure got me down to a white-gray screen delay time of only about 4-5 seconds.  Note that the "--verbose" in the bless command is optional, but it will give you more debugging information that might be helpful if something still isn't working right.

In case it makes a difference, I should also mention that I wiped my hard drive before installing Xubuntu and accepted the default values for a full-disk install.  That ended up automatically partitioning my hard drive as GPT with the first partition as a 1MB BIOS Boot Partition (type 0xEF02), the second partition as ext4 for the root filesystem, and the third and final partition as 1GB of swap.  Xubuntu 32-bit always requires booting in BIOS mode, so the proper boot partition for me to feed to the "bless" command was "/dev/disk0s1", and the "--legacy" flag tells the Mac to boot using BIOS-compatibility mode.  Your specified boot partition and whether you use the "--legacy" flag or not would likely change if you're booting Xubuntu 64-bit in EFI mode, though I can't say I'd recommend that on this particular laptop unless you've upgraded and maxed out the RAM.

Comment: Worked for me I used a Lion Disk instead of Snow Leopard. Booting off CD took nearly 4 minutes, just adding that fact so others don't loose faith.